# Why is my mdadm raid-1 recovery so slow?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, raid, mdadm

On a system I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.  My raid-1 restore started out fast but quickly became  ridiculously slow (at this rate the restore will take 150 days!):

```
dimmer@paimon:~$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      1953513408 blocks [2/1] [_U]
      [====>................]  recovery = 24.4% (477497344/1953513408) finish=217368.0min speed=113K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

Eventhough I have set the kernel variables to reasonably quick values:

```
dimmer@paimon:~$ cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
1000000

dimmer@paimon:~$ cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max
100000000
```

I am using 2 2.0TB Western Digital Hard Disks, WDC WD20EARS-00M and WDC WD20EARS-00J. I believe they have been partitioned such that their sectors are aligned.

```
dimmer@paimon:/sys$ sudo parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.

(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA WDC WD20EARS-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  ext4

(parted) unit s

(parted) p                                                                

Number  Start  End          Size         File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  3907028991s  3907026944s  ext4

(parted) q                                                                
dimmer@paimon:/sys$ sudo parted /dev/sdc
GNU Parted 2.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA WDC WD20EARS-00J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  ext4
```

I am beginning to think that I have a hardware problem, otherwise I can't imagine why the mdadm restore should be so slow.

I have done a benchmark on /dev/sdc using Ubuntu's disk utility GUI app, and the results looked normal so I know that sdc has the capability to write faster than this. I also had the same problem on a similar WD drive that I RMAd because of bad sectors. I suppose it's possible they sent me a replacement with bad sectors too, although there are no SMART values showing them yet.

Any ideas? Thanks.

As requested, output of top sorted by cpu usage (notice there is ~0 cpu usage). iowait is also zero which seems strange:

```
top - 11:35:13 up 2 days,  9:40,  3 users,  load average: 2.87, 2.58, 2.30
Tasks: 142 total,   1 running, 141 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3096304k total,  1482164k used,  1614140k free,   617672k buffers
Swap:  1526132k total,        0k used,  1526132k free,   535416k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                  
   45 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   2:17.02 scsi_eh_0                                                                                 
    1 root      20   0  2808 1752 1204 S    0  0.1   0:00.46 init                                                                                      
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                  
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/0                                                                               
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.17 ksoftirqd/0                                                                               
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0                                                                                
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.02 migration/1
  ...
```

dmesg errors, definitely looking like hardware:

```
[202884.000157] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[202884.007015] ata5.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[202884.013728] ata5.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
[202884.013730]          res 40/00:00:ff:59:2e/00:00:35:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[202884.033667] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[202884.040329] ata5: hard resetting link
[202889.400050] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[202894.048087] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[202894.054663] ata5: hard resetting link
[202899.412049] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[202904.060107] ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[202904.066646] ata5: hard resetting link
[202905.840056] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[202905.849178] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[202905.849188] ata5: EH complete
[203899.000292] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[203899.007096] ata5.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
[203899.013841] ata5.00: cmd ec/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[203899.013843]          res 40/00:00:ff:f9:f6/00:00:38:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[203899.041232] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[203899.048133] ata5: hard resetting link
[203899.816134] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[203899.826062] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[203899.826079] ata5: EH complete
[204375.000200] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[204375.007421] ata5.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
[204375.014799] ata5.00: cmd ec/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[204375.014800]          res 40/00:00:ff:0c:0f/00:00:39:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[204375.044374] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[204375.051842] ata5: hard resetting link
[204380.408049] ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[204384.440076] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[204384.449938] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[204384.449955] ata5: EH complete
[204395.988135] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[204395.988140] ata5.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
[204395.988147] ata5.00: cmd ec/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[204395.988149]          res 40/00:00:ff:0c:0f/00:00:39:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[204395.988151] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[204395.988156] ata5: hard resetting link
[204399.320075] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[204399.330487] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[204399.330503] ata5: EH complete
```

Comment: Can you insert output of top?

Comment: @GiovanniToraldo first ~15 lines of top added, sorted by cpu usage.

Comment: dmesg printing out hardware errors? You have a _high_ load average for no IOWait and no CPU time.

Comment: @StrangeWill yes thanks for bringing that up - added.

Comment: Tonight I will try unplugging other components to see if maybe the drive isn't getting enough power.

Comment: Check also smart status, and maybe you should unplug the defective drive and test it in another machine.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. When I opened the case I found that the SATA power cable for two drives was running between fins of the video card's heat sink. This also explains why the problem didn't show up at first. When the heat sink heated up, resistance in the power cable increased, decreasing voltage. Strangely enough the system disk (also receiving power from said cable) didn't seem to have any problems. I re-routed the SATA power cable and now I'm getting a more reasonable albeit fluctuating rate between 5-20MB/s. No more dmesg errors so far.

Comment: @chrishiestand please add you solution as an answer to the question, and then accept it as your answer after 48 hours :)

Comment: @pauska Here you go - unfortunately it's not a very satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being caused by hardware. Eventually I unscrewed all the HDDs from their chassis and moved them to new locations in the tower- and I tried unplugging peripherals that I knew I would not be needing. This fixed the problem. The raid array quickly rebuilt and my raid array has been stable for months.

Unfortunately I do not know what specifically caused the problem. I am guessing that something put noise into a data link, but I really have no clue. My motherboard is an Asus P5WDG2 WS Pro, in case anyone else has a similar problem with this motherboard.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help - this ended up being an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Disable write cache on hdd's in raid hdparm -W 0 /dev/sdX. Also try dont load disks that are rebuilding.

You can also try to speed limit your sata  to 150 MB (look's like they are connected to motherboards sata ports, that lags).

Comment: Thank you - I think this boosted my recovery speed from 60K/sec to 350K/sec.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck on it just being a power draw problem (though I got this error when the firmware on my hard drive went bad too), I'm seeing a hefty amount of activity on a kernel bug surrounding this.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/linux/+bug/256637

Maybe this applies to you? I can't get on the Linux kernel bug tracker so I can't tell what versions it showed in, and if it was ever fixed (and how that relates to 10.04).

You didn't migrate this RAID to this Ubuntu box did you? You've been running this RAID on this chipset for awhile, correct?

Comment: A kernel bug is another good suggestion. I have considered upgrading to 11.10 to see if that fixes it. If I come up with nothing else I will try it.

I had previously had a hardware raid controller that worked fine on this system. The problems began when I upgraded to 2TB drives so I ditched the old hardware raid for software raid. Under hardware raid, one of my drives would also fall out of the raid array and I couldn't figure out why. But then I had similar problems on software raid.

Comment: I've also had problems with partition block devices not being created by the kernel. For example, sometimes /dev/sdc1 would not be created at boot. I just assumed I had made a mistake partitioning, but perhaps it's because of this underlying problem.